# Limit of a function at point 0

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

[image: [enter image description here]]

Hi, Can you explain to me how it is possible to calculate a derivative at the zero point **without calculating the limit at zero?**

here is translation of this question:

*Show that the zero function is differentiable on all *ℝ* without calculating a limit*

edit: is this possible solve this question by use extend function like $g(x)$. Thus I can eliminate $0/0$ uncertainty?

Comment: Just asking, but you couldn't just make the observation that, for all $x\neq y\in\mathbb{R}$, we have that $\frac{0(x) - 0(y)}{x - y} = 0$? I choose to denote the zero function by a zero

Comment: can we define a function such that?  $0(x)$

Comment: I mean, is just notation, you could call it $f$, $g$, $\alpha$, whatever

Comment: what is the difference between $f(x)-f(y)$ and 0()−0(). I mean why did you define function like this instead of define $f(x)$

Comment: The way to show that will depend on what you can assume as known. If you know that a constant function is derivable, it is done. If you know that a linear function ($f(x) = ax+b$) is derivable, it is done too. But **I** cannot know what you have been taught so far...

Comment: yeah I know constant function is derivable but how can we show it without using limit? that's the point

Comment: I think the question is a bit unclear. A derivative is by definition a limit, so when asking "Calculate a limit without calculating a limit" I believe a bit more clarification is required. Do you have other examples of exercises like this where you "don't calculate a limit" to solve them?